# Open mapping theorem $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: reference-request, several-complex-variables

Is there any analogue of open mapping theorem for function $f:\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$, $n>1$? I found some questions posted here(discussing similar problem) but couldn’t find any theorem in this direction.

Any references for such a result?

Comment: Found this reference on the French Wikipedia page for the theorem, it might have what you are searching for? [Ludger Kaup, Burchard Kaup, Holomorphic functions of several variables:an introduction to the fundamental theory. Walter de Gruyter, 1983](https://books.google.com.na/books?id=4YVXCgewhTIC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false). Theorem 6.3 covers the case $f : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ and a counterexample for higher dimensions on the range is given, but I have no clue whether one can adapt the theorem, so I won't make it an answer. Hoping you'll find what you want though.

Comment: A holomorphic map is open unless it's image has complex dimension $<n$.